# Slider in Modal does not show until I resize the screen

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, slider, bootstrap-modal, window-resize

I have a slider inside of a modal. However, on modal show, the slider does not show on the screen. When I resize the window manually, it would appear.

I've attempted to do some research regarding this issue and individuals have stated that the problem is because the modal is hidden at the start and there are issues with the size calculations.

I have tried to do a manual resize of the screen when the modal is opened but it does not work.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
        if (typeof(Event) === 'function') {
          // modern browsers
          window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize'));
        } else {
          // for IE and other old browsers
          // causes deprecation warning on modern browsers
          var evt = window.document.createEvent('UIEvents'); 
          evt.initUIEvent('resize', true, false, window, 0); 
          window.dispatchEvent(evt);
        }
      });
    </script>
```

There are no error messages but its just a visual glitch.

Edit: This is the code for my modal

```
<div class="portfolio-modal modal fade" id="portfolioModal1" tabindex="-1" 
role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="close-modal" data-dismiss="modal">
      <div class="lr">
        <div class="rl"></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
          <div class="modal-body">
            <!-- Project Details Go Here -->
            <h2 class="text-uppercase">Title</h2>
            <p class="item-intro text-muted">Subtitle</p>
            <img class="img-fluid d-block mx-auto" src="img/portfolio/01-full.jpg" alt="">
            <p style="text-align: left;">Description 1</p>
            <p style="text-align: left;">Description 2</p>

<!--Script for Carasusel-->
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/publicalbum@latest/embed-ui.min.js" async></script>
    <div class="pa-gallery-player-widget" style="width:100%; height:480px; display:none;"
    data-link="https://photos.app.goo.gl/CSV7NDstShTUwUZq5"
    data-title="Mr. Monstro"
    data-description="Mr. Monstro is a great traveler. He visited Madeira, Poland, but also Georgia, Italy ...">
    <img data-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/XlH6wo2PzrAEqmplYrZwV0fI-2TafTT6BRwZhKDfZSHd_zT7HIdPyPWd3Xuqhn1QQADuTJ32QFmcgYiTOEU0sC4Bvf-VyTIiq-DxxEaxIeWDYyUK_VjaW8-zrMGBvekDZT77lpduYQ=w1920-h1080" src="" alt="" />
    <img data-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/HISe-DV_b4gjLvSEGzrJlsqBU2rSE8uQpSqHHKTPihg_Ax9VtfCrOrvdXF01raBeBleAWQKI7Hfb4_w9vZeJKFymQfNTlubwXxTBTbqGTPwjg7S0CBtQsQJqsspvIhD9c-pniSZrEw=w1920-h1080" src="" alt="" />
    <img data-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/05lhR1IAQY_B9rdQ_GvHDNLe1lJsSPyyuDeIMkt--gDDAnO2_EATwif7-sfNd2K_48RvyqKmN-u2svKZ06yfh8bnrbQ5kBUrIHfZvWheTzDGhIeFd1roPor-F_BycJmVKbQO6a9EaA=w1920-h1080" src="" alt="" />
    <img data-src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/VvK__Vx8kpPTP57WZPLblacZbTE0NqWeIGTyHSQ8Rq9pvOpWQG_CQE_tOc6jHPtj02XIBYa0Zo9fWbXXQyNYs9hDGGj34QibKFJky4W9nYBpSb57OwxiQoDyo25vzIXMTN2SNxuzqg=w1920-h1080" src="" alt="" />
</div>
<ul class="list-inline">
    <li>Date: July 13 - August 11</li>
    <li>Category: Events</li>
    <li>Partners: THD</li>
</ul>
<button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
              <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
              Close Project</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what slider do you use?

Comment: @ArtemGoldsmith I'm actually using this custom one made called public album by Pavex that converts Google Photo albums into a slider. https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/embedding-google-photos-albums

Comment: When are you initializing your slider? Maybe you should try to init it on show.bs.modal?

Comment: I am initializing the slider inside the modal body. Reason being, I have multiple modals and I will have sliders in all of them.

Comment: @ArtemGoldsmith I added my code to it, could you please kindly check? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Public album gallery decorator using Google closure, and this event is fired only if the screen is really resized. Look at the source code of **ViewportSizeMonitor**:

[`if (!goog.math.Size.equals(size, this.size_)) {`](https://github.com/google/closure-library/blob/85f43eaab34e5a5c7403831ee8df31aba8fa0f6d/closure/goog/dom/viewportsizemonitor.js#L160)... at line ~160.

You will need block automatic decorator, by changing the name of class, add an element ID and decorate the widget manually with the following code:

`var widget = new GalleryPlayerWidget();
widget.decorate(document.getElementById('widget1'));`

Check the last update information about widgets and demo:
https://www.publicalbum.org/blog/carousel-slideshow-gallery-widget-july-update#tiny-widget-api.

Comment: Thank you for your support pavex. I tried changing the code to have the widget decorate on show.bs.modal but it is still facing the same problem.

EDIT: Got it working, instead of using show.bs.modal, use shown.bs.modal indtead.

Comment: @JW: Yes, bootstrap snown.bs.modal is better in this case. Don't forget to block the decorator so that runs ones at start only. If the window size changes, you can add the `widget.update()` method.

Comment: hey @pavex is your website down? Its showing me a 404.